# Problems deleting File PHP

Tags: php, sql, unlink

This is my code to pull information from my sql database and then I want to delete the .txt files in each directory, but I can't seem to figure out why it won't delete the files.

```
<?php

session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'];

$id = array();
$id = $_POST['selected'];

//Include database connection details
require_once('config_order.php');

//Connect to mysql server
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if (!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
}

//Create query
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `PropertyInfo` WHERE  `order_number` =  '$id[0]'");

// display query results

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $c_name = $row['clientname'];
    $sitestreet = $row['sitestreet'];              
    $inspector = $row['inspector'];
}
mysql_close($link);

$client_name = str_replace(" ", "_", $c_name);
$site_street = str_replace(" ", "_", $sitestreet);

$client_name = "{$client_name}.txt";
$site_street = "{$site_street}.txt";

$client_path = "/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/Members/$user/$inspector/Orders/Clients";
$inspection_path = "/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/Members/$user/$inspector/Orders/Inspections";

if (unlink($client_path . "/" . $client_name)) {
    echo 'File Deleted';
} else {
    echo 'File could not be deleted';
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the output from you script?  Are any errors or notices being posted?

Comment: What exactly happens? What error do you get? What gets output?

Comment: All I get is "File could not be deleted"

Comment: Can you do an ls -ld of one of the parent directories and post it here. I suspect permissions problem.

Comment: Do you have the right permissions to delete the file?

Comment: The sample code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html), which is a very serious [security risk](http://bobby-tables.com/). To fix this hole, switch from the outdated mysql extension to [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) and use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/PDO.prepared-statements), passing the values as parameters to the statement rather than interpolating them directly into the string. If you need a PDO tutorial, try ["Writing MySQL Scripts with PHP and PDO"](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html). The site you save may just be your own.

Comment: The line `$id = array();` has no effect, since `$id` is overwritten the next line. A `while` loop to fetch result rows shouldn't be used in this case. If there is only supposed to be one matching row, simply fetch it from the result. Make sure you test the retrieved value in case there were no matching rows. If the query might return more than one matching row, rewrite it to return just one, since that's all you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because your `while` loop is overwriting the `$c_name`, `$sitestreet` and `$inspector` variables. This means you will only ever delete the last file.

Is this what you were trying to do? (*Edited Again...*)

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `PropertyInfo` WHERE `order_number` IN (".mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',',$id)).")");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

  $inspector = $row['inspector'];
  $client_name = str_replace(" ", "_", $row['clientname']).'.txt';
  $site_street = str_replace(" ", "_", $row['sitestreet']).'.txt';

  $client_path = "/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/Members/$user/$inspector/Orders/Clients";
  $inspection_path = "/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/Members/$user/$inspector/Orders/Inspections";

  if (!file_exists($client_path.'/'.$client_name)) {
    echo "File $client_path/$client_name does not exist!\n";
  } else echo (unlink($client_path.'/'.$client_name)) ? "File $client_path/$client_name was deleted\n" : "File $client_path/$client_name could not be deleted\n";

}
mysql_close($link);
```

Comment: for right now I just wanted to get it working to delete 1 file.  Once I got that working, I need to be able to delete multiple files that were selected.

Comment: Dave, how would I get it to delete multiple files that were selected?

Comment: @Jason How are you selecting the files? What's going on on the web page? What does the posted data look like?

Comment: What I'm doing is entering search criteria (Name, Address, Ect Ect).  Then the orders that are based on my criteria are displayed on the webpage with checkboxes.  Below is my code for that:
        
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                echo '<tr><td>';
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="'.$row['order_number'].'"/>';
                echo '</td>';
                foreach ($row as $key => $value)
                    echo '<td>'.htmlspecialchars($value).'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        ?>

Comment: So basically if 2, 5, 10 or all order are selected,  when I get to the code in my original post, I want to be able to delete all the files that were selected.

Comment: @Jason Use MySQL's `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... IN` syntax in combination with PHP's `implode()` - see my edited code above. I have just modified the query line, the loop remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try some extra debugging:

```
$realpath = $client_path . '/' . $client_name;

if (file_exists($realpath)) {
   if (is_writable($realpath)) {
       if (unlink($realpath)) {
            echo "$realpath deleted";
       } else {
            echo "Unable to delete $realpath";
       }
   } else {
      echo "$realpath is not writable";
   }
} else {
   echo "$realpath does not exist";
}
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, and I get an HTTP Error 500 now.

Comment: What's in the server's error log? It'll have much more detail than what you get in the browser.

Comment: You will need to remove the `P` on the same line as the first `else`.  (don't have edit comments permission yet, or else I would update it myself)

Comment: Ok, it's telling me that the file does not exist.  But I am looking at the file in SSH.  I am in the same directory, and I see the file right in front of me lol.

Comment: Does your webserver process have access rights to ALL of the directories above the one the file's in?

Comment: *Tip:* To avoid an extra `file_exists` call, simply check for `$realpath !== false`. And that last `else echo` there will never print the filename, because if the file does not exist, `realpath()` will return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

On first glance, this is a problem,  *if* `$_POST['selected']` is not an array:

```
$id = array();
$id = $_POST['selected'];

...


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `PropertyInfo` WHERE  `order_number` =  '$id[0]'");
```

You are instantiating `$id` as an empty array, then *overwriting* it with `$_POST['selected']`, so `$id[0]` is the first character of the string `$id`.

For example, if `$_POST['selected']` is `12345`:

```
"SELECT * FROM  `PropertyInfo` WHERE  `order_number` =  '$id[0]'"
```

is equivalent to:

```
"SELECT * FROM  `PropertyInfo` WHERE  `order_number` =  '1'"
```

Either don't try to access it with an index or do `$id[] = $_POST['selected'];` to *add* the element onto the `$id` array instead.

Whether that is an array or not, you **do** need to either [sanitize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) that input before you insert it into the query or use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), though!

Comment: `selected` could be the name of a group of form elements, in which case it would be interpreted by PHP as an array. So, `$id[0]` could indeed be a full string. Your sanitization point is valid, however.